# How can I search Yandex for specific file types?

Tags: yandex-search

Let's say I want to search Yandex for a specific file type, like a pdf. How can I do it?

Answer (score 4):

The method to add a filetype to yandex is

```
mime:pdf
```

This can go anywhere in the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

For example you can do this with:

> filetype: pdf

If you want to have further information e.g. Checklist and iOS or Android (just an example) write:

> filetype: pdf (Checklist OR checklist) AND (iOS OR Android)

three are different filetypes:

- filetype: doc (MS Word)
- filetype: rtf (rich Text Format)
- filetype: txt (Plan text document)
- filetype: xls (Excel)